# Show ellipsis (...) only if the number of characters exceeds limit defined in substr

Tags: count, limit, characters

I'm limiting the number of characters in the title with `substr`. But even if the title is less than 50 characters, being shown the ellipsis (...). I would not display the ellipsis if the title does not exceed the limit of 50 characters.

```
$title = substr( $title, 0, 50 ) . "...";
```

> Title of my post ...

(Incorrect: Title less than 50 characters in this case should not display "...")

> `Title of my post that exceeds 50 characters ...`

(Correct: Title longer than 50 characters are cut and accompanied by "...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the form you have posted this is more of PHP question - you could use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) functions to determine length of original title and apply ellipsis conditionally.

However in WP context you should consider using [`wp_trim_words()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_trim_words/) since trimming based on words looks tidier and it will take care of appending string of your choice whet cutting.

Comment: Thanks @Rarst, did not know `wp_trim_words`, I'm checking ...